# (.NET Core Api) What is the difference between passing an object and passing a parameter to an action?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have a **.NET Core web API** with crud functions

when I pass an object like `(Product obj)` as json serialization to an action, its value arrive to the action well [as you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbmE7.jpg)...

But, when I pass a parameter like `(int id)` as json serialization, the value not arrive to the action [as you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5Cqy.jpg)

the only way is to pass the parameter as **Query String** like `?id=5`, in this case the value arrive to the action [as you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Axwb6.jpg)

Now, I need to pass parameter as json, so...

What is the difference between this 2 cases (json & query string)??

How could I pass parameter as json and not as query string??

---

this is controller code

```
  private readonly IProductRep rep;

    public ProductController(IProductRep rep)
    {
        this.rep = rep;
    }


    [EnableCors("allow")]
    [HttpPost]

    public IActionResult GetAllProducts()
    {
        try
        {
            return Json(new { Result = "OK", Records = rep.GetAllProducts() });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return Json(new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message });
        }

    }


    [EnableCors("allow")]
    [HttpPost]

    public JsonResult AddNewProduct(Product obj)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Json(new { Result = "ERROR", Message = "Form is not valid! Please correct it and try again." });
            }

            Product product = rep.AddNewProduct(obj);
           return Json(new { Result = "OK", Record = product });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return Json(new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message });
        }

    }


    [EnableCors("allow")]
    [HttpPost]

    public JsonResult GetProductById(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            return Json( new { Result = "OK", Records = rep.GetProductById(id) });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return Json(new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message });
        }

    }



    [EnableCors("allow")]
    [HttpPost]  
    public IActionResult DeleteProduct(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            rep.DeleteProduct(id);
            return Json( new { Result = "OK" });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return Json(new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message });
        }

    }



    [EnableCors("allow")]
    [HttpPost]

    public JsonResult EditProduct(Product obj)
    {

        try
        {
            return Json( new { Result = "OK", Records = rep.EditProduct(obj) });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message });
        }


    }
```

This is my client-side code (I'm using jtable)

```
   $('#container').jtable({
        title: 'Table of people',
        actions: {
            listAction:'http://localhost:62881/product/GetAllProducts',
            createAction:'http://localhost:62881/product/AddNewProduct',
            updateAction: 'http://localhost:62881/product/EditProduct',
            deleteAction:  'http://localhost:62881/product/DeleteProduct'
        },
        fields: {

            Id: {
                key: true,
                create:false,
                edit:false,
                list: true

            },
            ProductName: {
                title: 'Name',
                width: '40%'
            },
            Price: {
                title: 'Price',
                width: '20%'
            },
            ProductCode: {
                title: 'Product Code',
                width: '30%'
            }

        }


    });
    $('#container').jtable('load');
```

---

this is what happened with postman when trying to [send id as json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xu7T1.png)

but when I add id as a paramerter in routing and send it as querystring it works [as you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHdL9.png)

Comment: i didnt see is your get method marked as [HttpPost] or not but .net core did not support 'request body' for get calls, you can mark your get method with [HttpPost] and it should work

Comment: I tried both of the ( post & get )

Comment: how you call it? from postman?

Comment: Integers are scalar values. I would build a wrapper class containing one integer.

Comment: Please let us see the client side calling, or the headers and body if you are using the postman.

Comment: Please, do not post code as images

Comment: @JamshaidKamran I edited my post..

Answer (score 0):

For the first call you can make something like this:

public JsonResult AddNewProduct([FromBody]Product obj)

I think you can add an attribute like this

[HttpGet("api/GetProductById/{id}")]
public JsonResult GetProductById(int id)

this way you don't have to make a call like ?id=5

Hope this helps...

Comment: I tried [HttpGet] with both custom routing and default routing ...  as I did with [HttpPost]

Answer (score 0):

In c#, int is primitive data type (stores in stack & not in heap) and it is not an object. Hence, JsonSeriallizer can not serialize your id if its only int. Read about this here: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm

Though, if you want to pass id as json and not as query string, you can wrap this id within a class and you can serialize that object and can pass it through that. refer below example.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class PersonController : Controller
{
    public string Get([FromQuery] GetPersonQueryObject request)
    {
        // Your code goes here
    }
}

public class GetPersonQueryObject 
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

I would suggest if you just needs to retrieve the data from API, then should use GET http call. Also, GET is less secure compared to POST because data sent is part of the URL & Data is visible to everyone in the URL.

Comment: my problem start when I used jtable in my client-side and found out that jtable send id on "delete action" as json, I knew that beacause I tested the api by postman and I had the same result..